# MariaDB RDS instance "filling up" with nothing

Tags: mariadb, amazon-rds

we have a MariaDB RDS instance which has < 5mb of data in it, but is rapidly "filling up" to 400GB
we can't see what this data is
it's not in any of the rows
and if we do a select on everything that's in the db it comes out to .0003gb
even as the db becomes inoperable as it "fills" to capacity.

I just called Amazon support and they're confounded. Wondering if anyone else has seen anything like this and what the culprit might be.

Comment: Show us the commands that show 5mb and 400GB, and show us the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that this was all `tmp` database bloat from a runaway query that was doing something wonky.
The solution turned out to

`show processlist`

which returns all the running processes with their IDs
and then a

`kill [PROCESS ID]`

Amazon support was completely useless in figuring out what the issue might be so I'm adding this "solution" here in case it might be of use to someone else in the future.